# two way ranged lookup table, C#

Tags: c#, performance, data-structures

I need to take a design decision on some data structure for extremely quick access. Here the scenario :
I have to sync two variables of different growth rate. I have tabulated data of in the following format:

Range( Ai1, Ai2)  ~  Range ( Bi1, Bi2)    That is to say that the range Ai1 - Ai2 matches Bi1 - Bi2 for some i

Now given any Ax in the entire span of A I should be able to determine the appropriate range in (Bj1, Bj2) and vice-versa. Data type wise : A is int;  while B is float.

I don't know what would be the most appropriate data type for this translation ? My primary requirement is speed. Also any help in how this data struct can be implemented in C# would be helpful.

The problem is assured to fit in memory. Span of A can be approx the range 0 - 300,000, and the  size of range Ai1-Ai2 can be some where from 10 to 300 ; while the span of span of the float is 0 to 10,000.000  ( we use only 3 decimal places) and the size of range Bi1 - Bi2 can be something like 0.100 - 10.000

Another known fact is that A is assured to be continuous while B may not be. But both increase sort of simultaneously, but at varying rates.Also neither Ranges overlap. Both are  monotonically increasing.

So something like this can be expected:

(Ai1,  Ai2)  ~ ( Bi1, Bi2)

(1,78) ~ (13.454, 19.546)

(79,114) ~ (19.712,22.335)

(115, 198) ~ ( 22.678, 24.101)

query:  A = 99 , Expected Response: B range = (19.712,22.335)

query: B = 16.117 , Expected Response: A range= (1,78)

In case B is not in range forward roundoff is expected.

Thnx-Egon

Comment: I'm asuming our problem fits into memory? But I don't understand your question enteirly, you wanna do what with who? Could you maybe elaborate a bit?

Comment: elaboration is now provided as requested.

Comment: Can any of the ranges overlap?

Comment: Ranges don't overlap, Increase monotonically.

Comment: the most straight forward approach I can think of would be O(log n) doing a binary search over the A ranges to find the right range, then return the corresponding B range, and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this general approach:

1. Define `ARange` and `BRange`; and point them to each other:

   ```
   class ARange
   {
       public int Low;
       public int High;
       public BRange B;
   }

   class BRange
   {
       public float Low;
       public float High;
       public ARange A;
   }
   ```
2. Construct pairs of `ARange` and `BRange` classes by a factory method that interconnects both instances.
3. Store `ARange`s and `BRange`s in two sorted arrays.
4. Having a particular `a` or `b` value, use binary search to lookup the covering `ARange` or `BRange` respectively, and retrieve the interconnected opposite range.

Binary search will give you an `O(log N)` lookup complexity in the worst case, where N is the length of `ARange` and `BRange` arrays respectively. This particular weakly-typed [`Array.BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k7w8xwf.aspx) overload can give you a kickstart.

If you need a general purpose solution with good readability, you can overload comparison operations for pairs of `(int, ARange)` and `(float, BRange)`.

After this algorithm is implemented, consider these optimizations:

- define `ARange` and `BRange` as `struct`s to reduce the amount of dynamically allocated memory, improve locality of data, and reduce overhead;
- providing `ARange`s form a continuous sequence (i.e. without gaps), optimize out `High`, and keep pairs of `Low`, `B` and an upper bound delimiting the sequence (say, as an artificial element in the array);
- provide a custom binary search implementation which will allow you to compare ints/floats with `ARange`s/`BRange`s;
- another option to increase locality of data (and thus reduce CPU cache misses) is to break-up the classes into arrays of individual fields, hence in the binary search you can work with just the `Low` bounds, and access `High` and `A`/`B` for specific items only:

  ```
  int[] ALow;    // Lows of A-ranges
  int[] AHigh;   // Highs of A-ranges
  int[] AB;      // index into B-arrays from A-ranges

  float[] BLow;  // Lows of B-ranges
  float[] BHigh; // Highs of B-ranges
  int[] BA;      // index into A-arrays from B-ranges
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The crucial properties of your data is that for both `A` and the associated `B`, the ranges:

1. Don't overlap.
2. Increase monotonically.

These mean that a simple binary search should work effectively, and provide you with `O(log(n))` lookup.

Store an array of the interval-pairs in ascending order.

To perform a lookup (on, say, `A`), run a binary search on the `start` property of the "key" interval (in this case, `A`) to find the *highest* interval whose start is smaller than the item to search. Then check if that interval contains the item (`end >= toSearch`). The "value" (in this case, the associated `B` interval) is trivial to extract - it's part  of the same array-element.

A reverse lookup (i.e. from `B` to `A`) works in pretty much the same way.